# Unable to update existing document in Firebase using VUE

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

I have never used Firebase before this is my first stab at it using Vue.

I have a setup Firebase using Realtime Databas and set up my project so I can post using the below code in my .vue file

```
this.$http.post('https://MY_PROJECT_NAME.firebaseio.com/posts.json', {
                title: this.blog.title,
                body: this.blog.content,
                createdDate: this.$options.filters.fullMthDate(this.blog.publishDate),
                author: this.blog.author,
                active: true,
                closedDate: null,                
            }).then((response) => {
                this.$blogAdded = true;
                this.loading = false;
                this.$router.push('/');                
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

[image]

The thing I can't seem to find an answer to is how to then update this document when needed (e.g. user deletes an item, I want 'active' to become `false`)

I went for the above code as I was using net ninjas tutorials who set FireBase up this way.

I then do a `get` to list all items using below in my main component

```
this.$http.get('https://MY_PROJECT_NAME.firebaseio.com/posts.json').then(function(data) {
                return data.json();
            }).then(function(data) {
                var blogsArray = [];

                for (let key in data) {
                     const date = new Date(data[key].createdDate);
                     const todaysDate = new Date();

                    if (date <= todaysDate) {
                        data[key].id = key

                        blogsArray.push(data[key])
                    }
                }

                this.blogs = blogsArray;
                this.loading = false;
            });
```

And this displays them on my site

[image]

When the user clicks the tile they go to a page where they can 'Delete/Cancel' the post and it's here I am stuck. Below is the code I am using for displaying the selected item

```
data() {
        return {
            id: this.$route.params.id,
            blog: {},
            loading: false,
            closeModal: false,
            showModal: false
        };
    },

    beforeMount() {
        this.loading = true;            
    },

    created() {
        this.$http.get('https://MY_PROJECT_NAME.firebaseio.com/posts/' + this.id + '.json').then(function(data) {            
            return data.json();
        }).then(function(data) {
            this.blog = data;
            this.loading = false;
        });
    },

    methods: {
        showCloseBlogModal() {
            console.log(this.blog)
            VueEvent.$emit('show-delete-blog-modal', this.blog);
        }
    }
```

Then when the modal is displayed I get the following in the `console.log`

[image]
[image]

I need to update the 'active' value to `false` when they click 'Yes' using the below

```
methods: {
    deleteBlog() {
        // CODE HERE WHEN CLICK 'YES' TO CANCEL
    }
}
```